# Using WebClient, getting The SSL connection could not be established error sporadically but very often

Tags: c#, webclient, ef-core-5.0

This part of the app seems so simple but I keep running into the error in title.

```
    public static async Task getAndProcessReps(string DUNS, string apikey)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        string url = string.Format("https://api.sam.gov/entity-information/v2/entities?api_key={1}&ueiDUNS={0}&includeSections=repsAndCerts", DUNS, apikey);

        MemoryStream resp = new MemoryStream();
        string r = "";
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            bool retry = true;
            int retryCt = 0;
            while (retry)
            {
                try
                {
                    //resp = new MemoryStream(await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(url)));
                    r = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
                    retry = false;
                }
                catch
                {
                    retryCt++;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (retryCt > 3)
                        retry = false;
                }
            }
        }

        reps.HomeSAM result = r.CreateFromJsonString<reps.HomeSAM>();
```

I get the following error returned occasionally but often:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be establi
shed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication fai
led, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090321): The buffers supplied to
 a function was too small.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdap
ter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean asyn
c, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken c
ancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean asyn
c, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken c
ancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request
, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequest
Message request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessa
ge request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage r
equest, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToke
n)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Bool
ean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpC
ompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

I am using c# Core5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

I have seen some chatter about Windows 7 vs Windows 10 specifically about this part of the error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090321): The buffers supplied to
     a function was too small.
```

Is this my server's problem, or my code's problem or the endpoint?

Could my error be about them not accepting tls1.3?

Comment: @zaggler ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is managed on the 2nd line of code

Comment: Remove this: `SecurityProtocolType.Tls13`, you cannot use it, yet (not actually supported). (Unrelated) This:  `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;` should be `false`, you're not handling it. -- Side note: WebClient uses `Encoding.Default` unless otherwise specified, setting its `Encoding` property. You can get garbled text when downloading strings. Use DownladDataTaskAsync instead (so you can recover the text, eventually). Possibly, don't use WebClient at all, unless you're downloading from a well-known source (because you know the Encoding used beforehand and you can set it).

Comment: @Jimi would this ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; cause me getting about a 50% success rate? When I reprocess it works. I am really only using downloadstring because i wanted to "see" the data. i would prefer having a stream.

Comment: I am also seeing this error a lot: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.